# A linear operator between $C[0,1]$ and $C[0,1]$ defined as $Tf = f + \int f$; Show $T$ is an isomorphism

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, continuity

Define a linear operator $T:C[0,1] \to C[0,1]$ as follows:
$$Tf(x) = f(x) + \int_0^x f(u)du$$
It is easy to show that $T$ is a bounded linear operator. The statement also (1) claims that $T$ is one-to-one and onto, and (2) asks to compute $T^{-1}$. (Hence $T$ is an isomorphism due to a corollary of Open Mapping Theorem)

I need help to prove $T$ is onto: given any $g \in C[0,1]$, how to decompose it into a sum between a continuous $f$ and its antiderivative. I have trouble decomposing $g(x)=|x|$, not to mention bizarre functions like Weierstrass function. It seems impossible.

Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: Good question! :)

Comment: This exercise is related to something much more general: the Fredholm alternative, which (among other things) states that a [compact operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_operator) $K$ (of which $(Kf)(x) = \int_0^x f(t)\,dt$ is an example) on an infinite dimensional Banach space $E$ has the property that $\lambda I - K$ is surjective if and only if it's injective.

Answer (score 7):

You need to prove that for each $g\in C([0,1])$ the integeral equation
$$
f(x)+\int_0^x f(t)dt=g(x)\tag {1}
$$
has a unique solution. Then you'll show that $T$ is bijective. Note that
$$
\left(e^x\int_0^x f(t)dt\right)'=e^x\int_0^x f(t)dt+e^x f(x)=e^xg(x)\tag{2}
$$
After integrating $(2)$ over the interval $[0,y]$ we get
$$
e^y\int_0^y f(t)dt-e^0\int_0^0 f(t)dt=\int_0^y e^x g(x)dx
$$
i.e.
$$
\int_0^y f(t)dt=e^{-y}\int_0^y e^x g(x)dx
$$
Then we differentiate this by $y$ to get
$$
f(y)=-e^{-y}\int_0^y e^x g(x)dx+e^{-y} g(y)
$$
And we are done.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer. Totally solved my question! I didn't notice this is a regular ODE problem.

Answer (score 1):

If $Tf=s$, then $F=\int f$ is a solution of the ODE
$$F'+F=s,$$
equation with integrating factor $e^x$:
$$(e^xF)'=e^xF'+e^xF=e^xs,$$
$$F=e^{-x}\left(\int e^x s\,dx+C\right)$$
with $C$ s. t. $F(0)=0$. Finally,
$$f=F'.$$

Comment: Thanks for the help. Your solution is very helpful and concise.